# Using the same database-generated EF entities in multiple projects

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am trying to separate the database piece of my **C# WPF application** so I can use it in multiple projects but I can't figure out how to do it without repeating code somewhere.

Current state:

- Windows desktop WPF application, single project in single solution
- Project has **EntityFramework 6.3** package installed in NuGet
- **SQL Server Express** running on same laptop
- Database was designed directly in `SSMS`, and reverse-engineered into `POCOs` through the following process: `Add -> New Item -> Data -> ADO.NET Entity Data Model -> Code First from Database -> Choose connection string -> Choose database objects`. This creates a `.edmx` file with some other files underneath it including  a `.tt` file that I can expand to see all my entities
- On rare occasions when I need to change the database, I do it in `SSMS` and then follow the above process again to update the objects in the application

This application works well. But I would like to separate the database so that it can run on another machine, either in my house or in the cloud, so that I could write web-based or mobile clients that use the same database from another location. However, I can't figure out how to remove just the database piece from my WPF application without introducing other problems.

I imagine a situation where the database is running on a machine with a **RESTful web service** sitting on top of it and the original application is modified to access the web service instead of the DB directly.

So maybe the web service project itself is where I would use **EF6** to access the database and reverse engineer it into entities, so I can receive entities over the web service and insert/update them in the database. That makes sense.

In that case, the original WPF application would no longer need to have EF6 installed, or any connection strings or anything database-related, but it would still need to know about all the entities that have been generated from the database, because it would still have to create those objects to send them when calling the web service.

So do I create the `entities` from the database in a project and then copy the same `entities` into the other project? That feels like duplicating code. If I changed the DB I'd have to update the `entities` separately in each project. Or do I make an `"entities"` project that I access from both others with the `"using"` directive? Or make a class library `.dll`? I assume one of the latter would work, but I'm a bit lost as to how to approach this. Or maybe this requires a deeper re-thinking?

Comment: *Or make a class library* -- Of course! But this question is very broad. Can you pin it down to one programming problem with (tentative) code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly...

You could create the model references in a separate class library and use that library as reference in your WPF or wherever you want, just keep in mind that the connection will happen where the program is running like your wpfApp or webapi so you have to put all the configurations settings in the "entry point".